# Cash book record Inventory system

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am almost done with a small inventory system but i am having a "concept" problem.

The problem is with the cash record.

I have a page to make cash records manually with option of either credit or debit, but mostly this is for credit records as sales will automatically be stored in sales table and also stored cash table as debit.

so the cash table looks like this:

```
  Date       | description   | debit | credit  |
  2014-08-23 | sales         | 456   |         |
  2014-08-23 | transportation|       | 234     |
  2014-08-23 | donation      | 567   |         |
```

I am using the above table to calculate for profit per month (debit - credit = profit)

This is all working fine to check for month;y flow of cash.

The problem is i dont want it to be just for a month (the monthly cash flow is needed though and its fine already).

With the above i do a query like:

```
$date = date("Y-m");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cash WHERE date LIKE '$date%'"
```

so this will give me all for that particular month.

The main problem now is:

I want the starting cash for the next month to be the profit from the last month (balance brought forward) that will be able to show the profit of the business and not just the profit for a month.

I cant think of the best way to do this

**Edit (how i am doing it):**

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE cash 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 date DATE, 
 descs varchar (255),
 debit varchar(30),
 credit varchar (30)
);

INSERT INTO cash
(date, descs, debit, credit)
VALUES
('2014-08-24', 'balance b/f', '5000',''),
('2014-08-24', 'transportation','', '350'),
('2014-08-24', 'sales','2340', '');
```

**My Database query**

```
$date = date('Y-m');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cash WHERE date LIKE '$date%'" //this will get all from same year and month
```

**PHP page**

I now have a `$cashs` with array of the result of the SQL query. then i do

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>No/s</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Purpose</th>
                            <th>Debit</th>
                            <th>Credit</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php $i=1; $total=0; foreach($cashs AS $cash): ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $cash->date; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $cash->desc; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $cash->debit; $total+=$cash->debit; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $cash->credit; $total-=$cash->credit; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td><strong><?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                       </table>
```

This is working fine but what i want is a way to get the `$total` as used in the above code of the previous month also so it will be balance b/f as debit. That should be the starting balance for the new month.

[image: Picture of result]

Comment: how are you determining what the starting cash is for the next month? the profit from the last month? also can you post a sqlfiddle with a few months of data with expected results?

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes the starting cash for a month will be the profit from the last month. i will try to give a link to sqlfiddle

Comment: If you're doing accounting, make a [general ledger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_ledger) of some sort. Recording in separate columns is not necessary, you can represent those with positive or negative values. That makes `SUM(x)` represent the current account balance.

Comment: @user2666633 what would you like the final output to be?

Comment: @tadman but to display it on a table like the pic above i will have to do something like if($cash->amount<1){} to determine if its a credit of debit record right? i will try that out

Comment: @JohnRuddell as shown on the picture i attached thats how i want it to be but i want the first record to be the SUM() of -credit+debit of the previous month

Comment: so you want an additional row with the previous amount?

Comment: but i am thinking i know how to do that now if i can follow what @tadman said then i can just do SUM of previous month and use it on the table as the first record.

Comment: yes that is something close to what you need to do. here is a sql fiddle with your info. can you add another months of data? so that I can write a query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17e85

Comment: @JohnRuddell exactly that will be the base of the calculation, all credit record wwill bbe subtracted from it and debit added to it so th final balance will be SUM(-credit+debit) + previous balance

Comment: @JohnRuddell http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2947 i have added records for previous month

Comment: It's hard to find examples of implementations, but the accounting basics are pretty straightforward: All transactions represent the transfer of money *from* one account and *to* another if you're using [double-entry bookkeeping](http://tenonline.org/art/bsr/9712.html). From an account is a negative amount, to is positive. Normally everything sums up to zero. If you record a fuel expense, that's money out of one account (e.g. bank) and into another (e.g. expenses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so all I did was union'd a row before that gets the starting cash. I don't know if you want it to be in a different column or where you want it placed so I just added two extra columns. one for the date of the previous month with the starting cash and then the ordinary columns.. you can adjust this accordingly.

the key is using the date in the WHERE. so for you there will need to be a few tweaks.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(MONTH(date), '-', YEAR(date)) as 'Pervious Month',
    '' as id,
    '' as 'date',
    '' as description,
    '' as debit,
    '' as credit,
    SUM(debit) + SUM(credit) as "Starting Cash"
FROM cash
WHERE MONTH(date) = 7

UNION

SELECT '', c.*, '' 
FROM cash c 
WHERE MONTH(c.date) = 8
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efbff/1)

I'm just using month because I don't have the php setup.. but what you would do is change the `MONTH(date) = 7` in the first select to

```
date = $date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

and then the second select would be the same as what you had originally

```
WHERE date = $date
```

## EDIT:

if you want to change the stating balance from just the last month to everything before the current month then change

```
date = $date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

to this:

```
date < $date
```

Comment: @user2666633 sure thing.. I wasn't sure if you wanted extra rows or not so you can change that.. but you have to put in a blank value for the number of columns returned in the table :)

Comment: Thanks and if i want to do the sum(debit)-sum(credit) for the whole cash before the present month, how will i do that? sorry i am bad with sql writing

Comment: if you want it for everything leading up to that current month then you just need to do your date < the current months date